# Xamarin Xcode 9 Preview not available in VS 17 Preview Version 15.3

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, xamarin.ios

Following [this tutorial by Xamarin Release](http://releases.xamarin.com/category/preview/) I have successfully completed steps 1 - 13. As well as downloaded Xamarin.Mac and Xamarin.iOS 10.99. However when I open my project, Xamarin iOS remains the wrong version.
[image]

Yes Visual Studio Preview Version 15.3.0 Preview 7.0 is installed and the tutorial is Preview 3.0. My release is more recent so it should not be an issue.

If I search in File Explorer I see that I have Xamarin.iOS.dll version 10.14 installed. Why is it not installing Xamarin iOS 10.99?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting and reinstalling all Xamarin components and running through the tutorial again, I was able to successfully install version 10.99.

Even though this is the latest version Xamarin updater still asks if you would like to update. Upon accepting it reverts to the latest stable version. DO NOT UPDATE if you wish to maintain 10.99